# My Solr health check during docker compose up is failing in my local xm cloud instance

Tags: solr, docker, xm-cloud

I am having an issue with starting my `XM Cloud Local Docker` instance, using the `up.ps1` script.

It looks to be stopping specifically at this health check:

```
test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "try { $$statusCode = (iwr
http://solr:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS
-UseBasicParsing).StatusCode; if ($$statusCode -eq 200) { exit 0 } else { exit 1} } catch { exit 1 }"]
```

Manually checking this, while it is still in the waiting stage shows that this *should* work, as it is returning a `200` response, as per the image shown below:

[image: Solr manual health check whilst docker compose up is waiting]

But after 120 seconds, it's showing that the health check failed:

[image: Solr showing error on start]

Hoping someone else has encountered this issue too, and might have a resolution for me.

Bridgette

Comment: Can you please confirm if this Solr service is from container and not a native service separately installed on your system ?

Comment: Your screenshot shows port `8984` while your health check code is trying to connect to port `8983`

Comment: @MarekMusielak that is because from my local machine I can only access the forwarded port (8984 is the externally exposed port, 8983 is the port used within the docker network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, turns out that it was that docker was not adding solr (or any of the container names) to it's DNS... so when it was trying to iwr against http://solr:8983/*, it could not resolve solr. Found this out as mssql-init was also having some issue resolving the mssql container.

Not sure if this is due to the version of docker I was using, but I reinstalled an older version (4.26.1) that the other devs were successfully using and it works fine.

*shrugs*

Comment: We've had four other people who have been force-upgraded to 4.27.1, and this has broken all of them in the same way. There might be something in the docker-compose that is reliant on a deprecated feature... in case anyone else has this same issue.